# Which Macs will run Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I am wondering what models of Macintosh will run Ubuntu, and if so, which versions of Ubuntu?

I have an iMac G3 and a Model II eMac. I am looking to buy other Macs as well, but whatever is more relevant would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be some old versions of Ubuntu that will work with your old computers, but I would recommend that you get a newer Mac that will definetly be able to run the newest software. Find a model that you like, then Google around for tips and tricks for a seamless Ubuntu installation. All Macs (as far as I am aware) are able to run Ubuntu, but the bells and whistles may not work perfectly without a little work, most of which has already been done before, and documented.

In conclusion, find what Mac you want, Google around, and go for it.

Note: You may find this guide useful, although rEFIt is not maintained anymore (it should still work fine, though)

http://lifehacker.com/5934942/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-mac-and-take-back-your-powerhouse-apple-hardware

Comment: If you don't mind, please mark it as answered (the gray check in the circle under the down vote on this answer).

Comment: Instead of rEFIt you can use rEFInd.

Comment: @Jeremy I haven't tried those instructions, so I didn't want to recommend using rEFInd because I'm not positive it will work (although it should).

Comment: In fact it should work better than rEFIt as rEFInd is more up to date.

Comment: @Jeremy I'm aware, but I didn't want to say anything about rEFInd because I haven't done it myself (as I previously stated). I don't want to mislead him/her.